# How does MySQL execute an aggregate query with a limit?

Tags: mysql

Does it group all possible results and then send back the results found within the given `LIMIT`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page from the MySQL manual explains the ways in which it optimizes queries that use LIMIT:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/limit-optimization.html

In short, it doesn't just do the naive thing, which would be to compute the entire result set and then send you the first N rows.

There are some things that will prevent optimizations, including using a HAVING clause and using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS.

Comment: The linked page answers the question in this sentence:

"In some cases, a GROUP BY can be resolved by reading the key in order (or doing a sort on the key) and then calculating summaries until the key value changes. In this case, LIMIT row_count does not calculate any unnecessary GROUP BY  values."

Answer (score 1):

The `LIMIT` clause is only selection of the records returned - it has nothing to do with the value(s) returned from the query itself.  For example, if you use `LIMIT 10` on a query that only returns 5 rows - you'll only get 5 rows.  If the query returned 11+ rows, you'd only get 10 rows.  For a query using `LIMIT` to consistently return the same results, you need to specify an `ORDER BY` clause.

Think of the query occurring in the following steps:

1. Query without ORDER BY or LIMIT
2. `ORDER BY` criteria applied to query output from Step 1
3. `LIMIT` criteria applied to output from Steps 1 & 2

If there's no ORDER BY specified, the step is not performed.

Comment: right, but im asking if `LIMIT` is given the entire output of `GROUP BY` to limit